# Problems granting permission with google

Tags: hosting, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to setup the plugin **Post SMTP from wordpress**.

I have a **G Suite account** and everything is ok, until the last step where I need to grant persmission to send the emails. I go to the page where google asks if I'm sure with the page accessing to my emails.

After I click to allow, I've got a 403 error.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the scope at the end of the url that google returns for granting permision, after some research I find my server has a module that doesn't allow this scopes, so you need to turn it off just to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer may not be exact for the question asked but I just wanted to send mails from my wordpress website and it worked by adding your `From` mail address in cPanel Email settings.
Just search `Registered Mail IDs` in cPanel and add your email addresses in there you want to send mail from.

Most of the post says to modify `mod_security` or `.htaccess` file to get your work done but I found such a simple solution, worth a try.